# How can the method of spherical means be used to prove uniqueness of the wave equation?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I heard that the method of spherical means can be used to prove uniqueness of the wave equation solution for the initial value problem of a wave at time $0$ and velocity $0$. I've found almost no PDFs about this method. The only good one is [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/waveequation3.pdf), however it does not prove unicity.

I believe the proof is simple, but it's not something I'd come with because I don't have the intuition on why this method works.

Comment: A detailed exposition of the wave equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be found in Evan's PDE book. He uses the same method to derive Kirchhoff's formula (for even and odd $n$. I don't necessarily think its traditional to prove uniqueness via those means, because of the efficiency of the energy method to do so.

Comment: For the energy method, we suppose $$e(t) = \int_U w_t^2(x,t)+|Dw(x,t)|^2dx$$ where $w = u - \bar{u}$ is the difference between two solutions to the initial value problem for the wave equation, then show that $e(t) = 0$.